# What is a word that means "belief in the good nature of humankind"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one word that is explained as "the belief in the good nature of humankind".
It is not *philanthropy* or *humanitarianism*; rather, I am looking for one word to describe one's belief in philanthropists.

Comment: The perpetual-optimist fictional character that immediately comes to mind is Pollyanna, but I'm not sure how to turn her name into a belief system -- Pollyannaism?

Comment: <tongue-in-cheek>Does 'gullible' suffice?</tongue-in-cheek>

Comment: I was thinking 'gullible' or 'deluded'.  :)

Comment: Or naïve perhaps? ;-)

Comment: @JPmiaou somebody who shares the personality of Pollyanna is called 'a Pollyanna' and the word **polyannaism** is recognised and defined by Merriam-Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Pollyannaism :  the overly optimistic and benevolently cheerful state of mind and point of view of a Pollyanna -- it is an excellent choice for OP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest "humanism."  Various dictionaries define it in roughly-similar ways, but [Merriam-Webster has this](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/humanism):

> a system of values and beliefs that is
>   based on the idea that people are
>   basically good and that problems can
>   be solved using reason instead of
>   religion

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the closest match to what I want. Reading wuthering heights, the book talks about this.

Answer (score 4):

You might say someone like that is [Panglossian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/panglossian):

> **Pan·gloss·i·an**  (pn-gls-n, -glôs-, png-)
>   *adj*.
>   Blindly or naively optimistic.

The term comes from a character in Voltaire's *[Candide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candide)*, which "begins with a young man, Candide, who is living a sheltered life in an Edenic paradise and being indoctrinated with Leibnizian optimism (or simply Optimism) by his mentor, Pangloss."

Comment: +1 for Pangloss. That's the one I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 3):

"Optimist" is the first that comes to mind, but is not specific about humankind.

How about "Rousseauian"?

Also, my personal favorite, "naiveté"

Answer (score 1):

■ It would be a dangerous and biased way to use "humanism" in that case. Humanism is mainly define by the fact of giving price to human life. If you attach the concept of humanism to the belief that human nature is innately "good", then you threaten the core value of humanism (this belief about human nature has been badly shaken by science since the 80's). Giving price to life doesn't imply the need of a "good" human nature (cf. the [is–ought problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem)). The same apply to "benevolence" as it could merely be a learning and not an innate state.

■ "Naivety" or "optimism" are subjective and thus are more interpretations than definition of "belief in the good nature of humankind”

I suggest "Rousseauian" (like JeffSahol) which is based on the "Noble savage" belief:

> Rousseau believed that "nothing is more gentle than man in his primitive state".

This belief is link to what is called a "[naturalistic fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy)" and more precisely an "[appeal to nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_nature)".

Answer (score 1):

## altruistic

noun: **[altruism](https://www.lexico.com/definition/altruism)**
the belief in or practice of disinterested and selfless concern for the well-being of others.
"some may choose to work with vulnerable elderly people out of altruism"

**Similar**:
unselfishness, selflessness self-sacrifice, self-denial, consideration, compassion, kindness, goodwill, decency, nobility, public-spiritedness,
generosity, magnanimity, liberality, open-handedness, free-handedness
big-heartedness, lavishness, benevolence, beneficence, philanthropy,
humanitarianism, charity, charitableness, bounty, bounteousness.

**Opposite**:
selfishness
1.1 ZOOLOGY
behavior of an animal that benefits another at its own expense.

Source: Lexico

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose [benevolence](http://selfknowledge.com/9171.htm).

The primary definition of the OED for this word is:

> **benevolence**: Disposition to do good, desire to
>   promote the happiness of others,
>   kindness, generosity, charitable
>   feeling (as a general state or
>   disposition towards mankind at large).

Answer (score 0):

In psychology, "humanism" is the perspective that focuses on the belief that all humans are inherently good.

However, the definition of the word "good" is subjective, and science has disproved time and time again the axiom all humans are inherently good.

Comment: EL&U generally wants answers that are documented with some explanation or references.  You might therefore want to add to your answer so it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: +1 with Xanne, please provide references with your answers :)